# Python Multiprocessing - Passing values between child process

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

1. I have a single method named grep_phalanx_log whose functionality is to SSH to a machine and grep for some values.
2. My main method will call this method with different host names/credentials, log file name, grep pattern.
3. So, I need to grep for a SAME pattern in two different servers in PARALLEL. If the match is found in one server, I want the other server to stop grep-ing. If the pattern is not found in both the servers for a specified time, my method grep_phalanx_log will return a negative value. Based on the negative value, I have to proceed with some other requirement.

```py
class eventFlowTestNfx(object)
    def grep_phalanx_log(self, host_name, username, password, grep_cmd, timeout=10, time_to_monitor=20):
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        Log.info("Grep command to be executed: %r" % grep_cmd)
        try:
            ssh_client.connect(host_name, username=username, password=password, timeout=timeout)
            end_time = time.time() + time_to_monitor
            while time.time() < end_time:
                ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr =  ssh_client.exec_command(grep_cmd)
                output = ssh_stdout.read()
                if not output:
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    Log.info("NFX: Match message from %r is %r" % (host_name, output))
                    return output
            if not output:
                Log.error("FAILED: Message not processed.")
                Log.error("Host Name: %r and grep command: %r" % (host_name, grep_cmd))
                raise Exception("NFX agent could not process message")
        except:
            Log.error("End to End flow is broken, check the logs!")
            return -1
    def main(self):
        for cr_dict in correlation_list:
            cr_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.grep_phalanx_log(), args=(cr_dict["host"], cr_dict["username"], cr_dict["password"], cr_received_cmd_skeleton,))
            cr_process.start()
```

So, I have my code stared 2 process, I am not sure how they will talk to each other and terminate the other.

Comment: Your code has multiple errors unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `time.sleep(1)` with:

```
if not output.strip(): # blank output
    is_found = found.wait(1) # sleep >= 1 second unless found
    if is_found:  
        break # stop grepping
else: # found something
    found.set() 
    ...
    return output
```

where `found = multiprocessing.Event()`: creat it in the parent process and pass to each child.